# Greeting on Lag B’omer

Tags: lag-ba-omer

How do people greet each other on Lag B’omer? For example, on a festival, one would say חג שמח. Is there an improper way (according to Halacha) to do so?

Comment: Lag sameach? :)

Comment: @JoelK I suppose we should vote for the best comments in a quarter as well! :-D

Comment: @JoelK *L'ag (לעג שמח) ;)

Comment: @Oliver ;) (Apologies for the lag in my response time...)

Answer (score -2):

The traditional formula for the day is "Today is thirty-three days, which is four weeks and five days, of the omer."

This is not actually a greeting, but the Shulchan Aruch ([Orach Chayim 489:4](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayim.489.4?lang=he)) specifically recommends *not* saying "today is x days" before counting the omer with a blessing, because by doing that you fulfill your obligation and can no longer say a blessing before counting it. It would follow that using "today is thirty-three days" could potentially be an improper way to greet someone.

Obviously this doesn't mean that you can't use "today is thirty-three days" as a greeting, but that if you do so for the first time that day, you should say it with a blessing, with the intent to fulfill the commandment, and with the number of weeks in order to fulfill the commandment in the best possible way.

Comment: I think the OP may be looking for an equivalent of something like ‘Good Yom Tov’

Comment: @Shmuel I understood that, but he also asked if there is an improper way to do so

Comment: I see, very well

Comment: Saying "You remember our ex-coworker Fred? He was arrested yesterday on fraud charges" is also an improper way. So are lots of other things.